# Problem understanding the intuition behind Slepian's inequality

Tags: stochastic-processes, gaussian-process, probability-inequalities, inequality

Slepian's inequality is defined as follows:

Let $X\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $Y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ be centered Gaussian random vectors such that
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}X_iX_j&\geq \mathbb{E}Y_iY_j,\quad \forall i\neq j\\
\mathbb{E}X_i^2&=\mathbb{E}Y_i^2,\quad \forall i=1,\cdots,n
\end{align}
Then for every $\tau\in\mathbb{R}$, we have
\begin{equation}
P\left[\max_{1=1,\cdots,n}X_i\geq \tau\right]\leq P\left[\max_{1=1,\cdots,n}Y_i\geq \tau\right]
\end{equation}
and consequently,
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\left[\max_{1=1,\cdots,n}X_i\right]\leq \mathbb{E}\left[\max_{1=1,\cdots,n}Y_i\right]
\end{equation}

While this mathematically (using pseudometrics) makes perfect sense, intuitively I struggle to follow it. If the covariance function of the Gaussian process $X$ is greater or equal than the covariance function of $Y$, as per the first line of the equation, would not that imply the process is more persistent / explosive, and hence dominating process $Y$? I guess what I am asking, doesn't the covariance assumption imply process $X$ grows faster?

Comment: This is a correlation assumption rather than a covariance assumption. The intuition could be that, as the $X_i$'s are more correlated, they make smaller independent jumps.

Comment: The assumptions are that each pair of $X$ variables has a greater correlation than the corresponding pair of $Y$ variables.  For intuition, then, consider such a pair (that is, let $n=2$).  When the $X$ variables are strongly positively correlated, they behave essentially like a *single* variable that has been duplicated.  The more weakly correlated $Y$ variables, on the other hand, provide *two* chances of exceeding any threshold $\tau.$  Go on from there.

Comment: Thank you both your responses were immensely helpful!